# How can I make a comment visible on user's dashboard after they approve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a user, they can login and add books to a platform. They also can see when other people add books. They can click 'Show' button and see the details of a book and can comment in the show section. I want this comments to be seen only if the user approves it.
So I need

> 1- a notification on user's dashboard when someone commented on one of
> their books

> 2- when they click on the notification there would be a page that has
> a 'approve the comment' button and when the user clicks that
>
> 3- I want this comment to be visible under the book (in show.html.erb)
> and in the user's dashboard (like a comments list).

What I did so far: I have my models; book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :author, presence: true

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb (dont mind the extra code I'm gonna clean it up later. I'm new to this so I'm having trouble understanding what does what for now):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_create :set_username

  has_many :books 
  has_many :comments
  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  attr_writer :login

  def login
    @login || self.username || self.email
  end
  
    # validates_length_of :username,
    #                     :within => 5..50,
    #                     :too_short => " is too short, must be at least 5 characters.",
    #                     :presence => true
  private
  def set_username
    self.username = self.email.split("@").first
  end

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup

  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  else
    if conditions[:username].nil?
      where(conditions).first
    else
      where(username: conditions[:username]).first
    end
  end
  end
end
```

here's books show.html.erb:

```
<p style="text-align:center">
  <%= link_to 'Shared Books', root_path %>
  <%= link_to 'New Book', new_book_path %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @book.title %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @book.author %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Page Count:</strong>
  <%= @book.page_count %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Share with others:</strong>
  <%= @book.hide_from_others %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @book.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.title %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.content %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_with(model: [ @book, @book.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :content %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<% if current_user.id == @book.user.id %>
  <p style="text-align:center">
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(@book) %>    
  </p>
<% end %>
<p style="text-align:center">
  <%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>
</p>
```

dashboard index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<table border='4', align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Page Count</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
   
    <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= book.title %></td>
      <td><%= book.author %></td>
      <td><%= book.page_count %></td>
      <td><%= book.user.username %></td>
      <td><%= book.hide_from_others ? 'Shared' : 'Hidden' %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', book_path(book) %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book) %>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', book_path(book),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>     

<%= link_to 'New Book', new_book_path %>  
<%= link_to 'Shared Books', root_path %>
```

comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @comment = @book.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    redirect_to book_path(@book)
  end
 
  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

dashboard controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = current_user.books
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  devise_for :users

  root 'welcome#index'
  
  resources :dashboard 

  resources :books do
    resources :comments
  end
  
end
```

finally this is generate model Comment migration:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content
      t.boolean :status
      t.references :book, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :books }
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I thought I add a status boolean, and somehow bind it with approve button. When `status == true`, comment would be approved and seen under the book. But I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add scope `approved` to your Comment model to select only approved comments.
`scope :approved, -> {where(status: true)}`

Then in your view books/show.html.erb change `@book.comments` to `@book.comments.approved`

To update a comment, you'll need to add update action to your CommentsController